# DeSerialize null values

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I'm trying to serialize a xml file into a class where a element can be empty

XML file

```
  <Status StatusId="1">
    <StatusName>Not inspected</StatusName>
    <Acute></Acute>
  </Status>
  <Status StatusId="2">
    <StatusName>Acute</StatusName>
    <Acute>1</Acute>
  </Status>
```

The class

```
 private int _acute;
         public int Acute
         {
             get { return _acute; }
             set
             {       
                   _acute = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Acute");

             }
         }
```

I have tried int? and `[XmlElement( IsNullable = true )]` but nothing works anyone know how to read in empty elemet without getting any errors.

Comment: What error are you getting? What error did you get when defining _acute and Acute as int?

Comment: I just get error in xml document when i use int? and element is empty. If i add value to element it works fine.

Comment: Is that the error? "error in xml document"? What exception is thrown? Perhaps it has a property telling you where the error in the XML is. XmlSerializer treats nullable value-types as nullable even if you don't specify that explicitly.

Comment: Sorry i cant be more epxlicit, im using Prism and the error is captured as as CompositeExcelption with output .Input string was not in a correct format.
Resulting in: There is an error in XML document (6, 5).

Comment: You may want to change your title to DEserialize null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making Acute an `int?` . Ints can't contain null, nullable ints (int?s) can.

EDIT: Note to self - read everything before responding.

Perhaps your problem is that `<Acute>` isn't actually missing from the XML, it's there but with an empty value, which doesn't translate to any int? Try removing the `<Acute></Acute>` line from the XML, and change the property back to int? .

Comment: and null won't be saved as empty element. It would be something like `<Acute i:nil='true' />`

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem , int? and <Acute xsi:nile='true'> . The <Acute></Acute> comes from a faulty xslt transformation of a dataset. Now i only need to figure out how to genereate the xml document with xslt without getting <Acute></ Acute> when the element is missing

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it isn't the *right* way to do it but I've handled this in the past by handling the conversion from `string` to `int` myself. Roughly:

```
 private int _acute = 0; // or assign to some more appropriate default
 [XmlIgnore]
 public int Acute
 {
     get { return _acute; }
     set
     {       
           _acute = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("Acute");
     }
 }
 // I kept mine as public but may be able to hide it at a minimal level that
 // serialization still works.
 [XmlElement(ElementName = "Acute")]
 public string SerializedAcute
 {
     get { return _acute.ToString(); }
     set
     {   
         Int32.TryParse(value, out _acute)
     }
 }
```

If you have a lot of these though it could get kind of ugly.

Comment: Also you need to put attribute `[XmlElement(ElementName = "Acute")]` to `SerializedAcute`

Comment: Good catch. I kept reading through the code comparing it to mine, but couldn't figure out what I was missing.